# How to flatten json into table

Tags: json, postgresql

I have just realised on my AWS Aurora postgres cluster having functions with temp_tables are not friendly with read replicas. I need to do a re-write (using CTEs) - anyway.... How do I take a json object with arrays nested and flatten them to a table like so:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "groupName": "TeamA",
      "groupCode": "12",
      "subGroupCodes": [
        "11"
      ]
    },
    {
      "groupName": "TeamB",
      "groupCode": "13",
      "subGroupCodes": [
        "15", "22"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the output table to be:

```
groupName  groupCode  subGroupCodes
TeamA      12         11
TeamB      13         15
TeamB      13         22
```

I know I can get most of the way there with:

```
SELECT j."groupCode" as int, j."groupName" as pupilgroup_name
FROM json_to_recordset(p_in_filters->'data') j ("groupName" varchar(50), "groupCode" int)
```

But I just need to get the subGroupCodes as well but unpacking the array and joining to the correct parent groupCodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first unnest the array, and then another unnest to get the subgroup codes:

```
with data (j) as (
values ('{
  "data": [
    {
      "groupName": "TeamA",
      "groupCode": "12",
      "subGroupCodes": [
        "11"
      ]
    },
    {
      "groupName": "TeamB",
      "groupCode": "13",
      "subGroupCodes": [
        "15", "22"
      ]
    }
  ]
}'::jsonb)
)
select e ->> 'groupName' as group_name, 
       e ->> 'groupCode' as code,
       sg.*
from data d
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(d.j -> 'data') as e(g)
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(g -> 'subGroupCodes') as sg(subgroup_code)
```